# How to receive DateTime Function values?

Tags: directus

I am getting an error

> Int cannot represent non-integer value 50.3

when querying `DateTime` functions. The request that is sent is:

```html
Host: ****.directus.app
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1164

{"variables":{"limit_1":50},"query":"query($limit_1:Int) {\r\nclinic(limit:$limit_1) {\r\nid\r\nstatus\r\nuser_created\r\ndate_created\r\nuser_updated\r\ndate_updated\r\nhomepage\r\nyear_of_foundation\r\nslug\r\nstreet\r\nstreet2\r\ncity\r\ncountry\r\nclinic_title\r\nstate\r\nzip\r\nverified\r\nivf_maximum_age\r\nivf_single_mother\r\nivf_female_couple\r\nivf_family_balancing\r\nivf_gender_selection_family_ballancing\r\nivf_gender_selection_medical_reason\r\nivf_surrogacy\r\nivf_hiv_positive_male_available\r\nivf_hiv_positive_female_available\r\nivf_hbv_hcv_positive_male\r\nivf_hbv_hcv_positive_female\r\nivf_fresh_donnor_eggs_available\r\nivf_frozen_donnor_eggs_available\r\nivf_anonymous_egg_donation\r\nivf_non_anonymous_egg_donation\r\ntranslations_func {\r\ncount\r\n}\r\nimages_func {\r\ncount\r\n}\r\npackage_func {\r\ncount\r\n}\r\nclinic_language_func {\r\ncount\r\n}\r\nparameter_func {\r\ncount\r\n}\r\npricelist_func {\r\ncount\r\n}\r\ndate_created_func {\r\nyear\r\nmonth\r\nweek\r\nday\r\nweekday\r\nhour\r\nminute\r\nsecond\r\n}\r\ndate_updated_func {\r\nyear\r\nmonth\r\nweek\r\nday\r\nweekday\r\nhour\r\nminute\r\nsecond\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}\r\n"}
```

and the error I am getting in response is:

```html
X-Powered-By: Directus
Vary: Origin, Cache-Control
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range
Cache-Control: no-cache
ETag: W/"143c5-1DGj+hRgYJO2/wwjrcCIWeftky8"
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 1bd2fdd679c28997d984e3cff5c0bc4c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: ATH50-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: L9_0FlLgba6qB-7EfC5wREtaLnmCx5C7bWDsTHIHV2_eEwgBO27ATw==
Content-Length: 82885

{"errors":[{"message":"Int cannot represent non-integer value: 50.333","locations":[{"line":71,"column":1}]}
```

Any idea what this may be and how can I fix it?